# Differentiate job history based on parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, parameters, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I would like to set up a Jenkins based CI system, where the job histories are dynamically managed based on the parameters coming from webhook triggers.

Currently, I can only trigger specific jobs, maybe with applying filters, but it will not handle jobs dynamically.

I aim for a solution, where a parameter (or group of parameters) identifies a job with its own history. If the job history does not exist, it is created automatically.

In the results, I would like to somehow mimic the behavior of the GitHub PullRequest plugin. The problem with it, that it is tightly coupled with GitHub but I need a more generic solution.

I see two marginally different solutions here:

1. Manage jobs

   Jobs can be managed based on the build parameters. The jobs dynamically created and deleted.
2. Filter builds

   The job remains the merged job containing all the Pull request for all the branches, and some UI features able to filter out the different histories from it based on the parameters.

I do not know if any of this is achievable with currently available Jenkins plugins, or if I have to implement something from scratch?

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Can you explain some more context around why you are trying to take this approach?

Comment: @AndrewGray
I am open for any solution to differentiate jobs or job histories.  
Unfortunately, git frontends can only parametrize the webhooks (triggers), so this is the only option to differentiate them.  
I would not really like to register different hooks for each and every new pull request manually.  
These approaches just seems to be the most possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was looking for the Multibranch Pipeline approach, just I didn't know about it yet.

That is actually doing the same that I described for GitHub and BitBucket.
I was lucky as my target was BitBucket.